# Passing function as a parameter and using in setInterval for javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval, anonymous-function

I am trying to pass a function as a parameter to other function and use that parameter in setInterval but for some reason it is not working.

```
function x(){
  var x1 = "parameter1";
  var y1 = "parameter2";
  y(parameter1,prameter2,function(){
      alert(y1);
  });
}
function y(parameter1,parameter2, func){
 //some code
 setInterval(func,1000);
}
```

After executing x it should display alert box every 1 second but it does not can you please help

P.S: If I call func from y  using func() it works well

Comment: You have an error on your script, you should use x1,y1 instead of paraneter1,paraneter2 on the first call to y. You should always use the javascritp console to check for error when one of your script does not work.

Comment: Where are `parameter1` and `parameter2`defined inside the `x` function?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your passed parameters in function y as x1, y1

Because you have to pass variables

```
function x(){
  var x1 = "parameter1";
  var y1 = "parameter2";
  y(x1,y1,function(){  //Replace your passed parameters here as x1, y1
      alert(y1);
  });
}
function y(parameter1,prameter2, func){
 //some code
 setInterval(func,1000);
}
```